# Why doesnt an added folder not show up in eclipse in project directory?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am the tutorials from here 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game
I added the resources link as in the tutorial, but it doesnt show up in eclipse after refreshing,  also I tried to create a new untitled folder, which also doesnt show up. Why?

[image]
[image]

--edit---

**These folders only show up, when I import the same project again in eclipse. Why?
Why wont an existing one refresh?**

Comment: I am assuming you tried refreshing the Package Explorer in Eclipse already...?

Comment: yes, I clicked refresh on my project's right click menu in the package explorer window

Comment: Possibly related: [Eclipse Mars - imported projects don't show up in Project/Enterprise Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45465437/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

It should work... try to close the eclipse and reopen it again. However, keep in mind that in some locations you are not supposed to create folder like in ***layout*** folder. or inside res folder.

Comment: wired...!! why don't you try to create the folder using eclipse itself

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the project in your eclipse is the same project you added the folder in, then is means you can add folder where you added it.

the folder is the untitled one ? Did you try a name without spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this now from a Gradle project that for some reason won't add the build folder that it created. I eyeballed the actual directory and the war file I created was there. gradle clean, war, bootRepackage didn't work. Neighter did closing the project or restarting clipse. All other gradle projects in the workspace didn't have the same problem.

My workaround was to delete the project WITHOUT deleting the files then importing them again.

Give it a shot if all the above doesn't work.